# What is the different between System.Web.Http.HttpPut Vs System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

What is the different between *System.Web.Http.HttpPut* and *System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut*?

Using [HttpPut] on the Web API project results the error 405 - The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.

Comment: Did you inherit your controller from `Controller` or from `ApiController`?

Comment: from ApiController

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They belong to two different frameworks. The pipeline flow of each is looking for specific attributes that belong to their respective namespaces.

The routing engine for the respective frameworks are not aware of the other so if a Web API attribute is used on a MVC action it would be just as if there were no attribute at all, hence the 405 error encountered.

Make sure that the correct namespace is used on the correct controller type. If both namespaces are being used in the file then be specific by calling `[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]` for Web API actions

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPut]
public IHttpActionResult Put([FromBody]MyModel model) { return Ok(); }
```

and `[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut]` for MVC actions

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPut]
public ActionResult Put([FromBody]MyModel model) { return View(); }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However I didn't face any error when I use [HttpGet] either System.Web.Http.HttpGet or System.Web.Mvc.HttpGet,  Only in [HttpPut].

Comment: Check your web config to see it PUT Verb is allowed for requests.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a MVC system application you should use System.Mvc.HttpPut
It is the correct way because mvc pattern has many things that required mvc controls / methods.